Is it possible to write recursive monadic parser in OCaml?
Assuming we are going to parse an expression like this:
Exp := Mul
Mul := Add {'*' Add}
Add := Literal {'+' Literal}
Literal := number | '(' Exp ')'

In Haskell, we can write a parser like
exp = mul
mul = do
   foo <- add
   bar <- many (char '*' >> add)
   return -- something
add = do
   foo <- literal
   bar <- many (char '-' >> literal)
   return -- something
literal = number <|> do
   _ <- char '('
   x <- exp
   _ <- char ')'
   return x

But in ocaml, the "same" code like this:
let rec exp = mul
and mul = (* ... *)
and add = (* ... *)
and literal = (* ... *) 

will cause a compilation error

This kind of expression is not allowed as right-hand side of let rec

I understand that it's because of the eager evaluation in ocaml. And now I have come up with two solutions, neither are as clean as haskell though.
let rec exp input = mul input (* the first one is to write the state as param explicitly, which is not monadic *)
and (* ... *)

let rec exp = lazy (Lazy.force mul) (* the second one is to mark every parser as lazy, which produces a lot of verbose code *)
and (* ... *)

Therefore, I wonder if there is a clean(i.e. do not repeat too much) way to write recursive monadic parser in ocaml? If not, are there some recommended ways to write clean parser manually?

What does "clean" mean? And why is it important that the parser is monadic?

It's important to play to a language's strengths and not try to directly translate code.

It is really a matter of taste whenever exposing when computation starts is cleaner or messier. Thus your first solution seems mostly fine to me, since it is merely stating clearly that computation only start once the input is provided.
Nevertheless, most OCaml parser combinator library will also expose a fix combinator to help expressing those recursive definitions.
For instance, with angstrom:
open Angstrom
let number = map ~f:int_of_string @@ take_while1 (function '0'..'9' -> true | _ -> false)
let exp = fix (fun exp ->
  let literal = number <|> (char '(' *> exp <* char ')') in
  let mul =
    let* left = literal in
    let+ rest = many (char '*' *> literal) in
    List.fold_left ( * ) left rest
  in
  let add =
    let* left = mul in
    let+ rest = many (char '+' *> mul) in
    List.fold_left ( + ) left rest
  in
  add
)

Finally, a more natural way to write such parser following an EBNF grammar might be to use menhir:
%token <int> INT
%token PLUS MUL LPAR RPAR EOF
%start <int> expr

%%

expr:
| t = term EOF { t }

simple_expr:
| i=INT { i }
| LPAR e=expr RPAR { e }

term:
| f=factor o=option(PLUS t=term {t}) { f + Option.value ~default:0 o }

factor:
| s=simple_expr o=option(MUL f=factor {f}) { s * Option.value ~default:1 o }

which is bit a longer, but is guaranteed to be implement the specified grammar (and will emit warnings in case of an ambiguous grammar).
